# CUPS + Canon MG5650: page cropped when printing duplex

Tags: cups, lpr

I am trying to print on my Canon MG5650 via CUPS. I have a driver "Canon MG5600 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.11" was selected.

I ran the following command to print "one-sided". the results seems good (left side of the image below):

```
lpr -P Canon_MG5600_series -o sides=one-sided document.pdf
```

However, when I ran flowing command to print "duplex":

```
lpr -P Canon_MG5600_series -o sides=two-sided-long-edge document.pdf
```

The first page got cropped at the top (right side of the image below).

I tried printing via the system dialog and via `lpr` and I got the same results.

[image: Printouts]

Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Hi Adam, would you please provide the command `lpr` that you had used for printing?

Comment: @Goro Sorry, added to the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a driver-related issue. After installing official printer drivers from the manufacturer it started working.